# Google Drive and Spreadsheet: is it possible to access a named revision programatically?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Currently trying to use https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client but this is meant to be a generic question.

I can access revisions for a given spreadsheet using the Drive API, but then I run into two issues:

1. Cannot seem to open a revision using the sheets API
2. Cannot access revisions by name

It appears as if named revisions were duct-taped on top of the Drive API in Google Sheets, but is there an API call I might be missing?

**Edit**: I can already list and download revisions. My question specifically pertains to accessing revisions *through* Google's API (e.g. without exporting the file) and accessing a [named revision](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/named-versions-new-version-history-google-docs).

Comment: Only partially. I don't believe the referred question concerns itself with named revisions.

Comment: admittedly, the linked answer seems to refer to the v2 API. meanwhile it is rather: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get - while one cannot directly access the revision, but one can get it, write to drive and then open the export. would assume, that else revisions would be in best case read-only, except the latest one revision at `HEAD` (which is accessible without problems).

Comment: I agree that the marked as duplicate is wrong as the referred question isn't a about named versions.